# Как вывести в AlertDialog нажатое нами изображение?

Tags: java

Мне нужно чтобы когда нажималось например, ImageClick1 открывался AlertDialog с нажатой нами изображением. Не могу понять что передать, getSrc или getDrawable

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.your_drawable);
...
AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
alert.show();
```

в метод `setIcon` вы можете передать или сам drawable (как я понял вы про вот это getDrawable) или интовое значение на его, например `R.drawable.your_drawable`